# How can I find the diagonal polynomials induced to multivariate polynomials equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, diagonalization, multilinear-algebra

I need to find the diagonal polynomials induced to this  equation:
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1x_2+x_3x_4-x_1x_3+x_1x_2x_3x_4$$

Topic:These restrictions are counted as

1 variable: 1 polynomial.

2 variables: if one variable is x, and the other four are y, we have four polynomials;
if two variables are x and the other three are y, we have $C_4^2 = $ polynomials.

3 variables: if one variable is x, another is y and the other three are z, the we have ?????????

4 variables: if one variable is x, another is y, another is z and the other two are w,then we have

For example, if we take $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_4 = x $, with independent identical units, we
get one diagonal (univariate) polynomial $$f(x)=x^2+x^4$$

What is the way to calculate the number of polynomials. Is there a better way or a theoretical basis?

Can anyone help me with clarification or references?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is a diagonal polynomial ?

Comment: Can you give us some examples for small values ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  ,,, For example, if we take $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_4 = x $, with independent identical units, we
get one diagonal (univariate) polynomial $$f(x)=x^2+x^4$$